# How to know the actual codification of a text stored in a MySQL table field?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a very simple question. I just need to determine the codification (UTF8, latin1) of a text stored in a MYSQL table field.

Comment: What programm do you use for managing MySQL? phpMyAdmin, SqlYOg etc.?

Comment: SQLyog at the moment. I can see some info in table properties, but I'm not sure whether is this the actual codification which previously saved data was stored with!

Answer (score 1):

I've used `SELECT COLLATION(column) FROM table LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the data will be stored according to the `charset` and `collation` settings that were in effect at the time the data was stored.

Which `charset` and `collation` values are used for a given piece of data can come from any one of [four places](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html)

1. Server Settings
2. Database Settings
3. Table Settings
4. Column Settings

All this information is discoverable through querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database